# Excel – Detect if 2 specific keys being pressed at once

Tags: excel, vbscript, keypress, onkeypress

I don’t know if this is possible. I am working with Excel and using VB script. Is there a way to detect if two keys are being pressed at the same time and which ones they are? Then if it is those keys that are pressed I can use an If/Then statement to do whatever processes I need to do?

I know if I have something like a combo box I can use the keydown feature to detect a single key pressed, but this will only work on one key and not two keys. Also, I am not using combo boxes, text boxes, or anything else. I am strictly using cells, so there doesn’t appear to be anything like keydown to detect even the press of a single key.

Again, I would need for it to detect two keys at the same time being pressed. I would also somehow like to get it to detect this at the workbook level as well, instead of each individual worksheet, since there are several worksheets and would like these pressed keys to work from one sheet to the next.

Please let me know if this is possible or not, but I have a feeling it is not possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the VBA `OnKey` function? It would work for something with Ctrl, Shift, and other such keys in conjunction with "regular" keys like "A".

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a good start, and no I haven’t tried to use this. I am looking up information on it. The problem is, I can't figure out where to place the onkey event. There does not appear to be any options that will trigger this as keys are being pressed. I have placed a marker next to it, so when code is ran it will be paused at this marker, but nothing will trigger this as I am pressing keys. I see articles where people are using this in Excel through an add on they created in Visual Studios, but I need to figure out how to do this directly in Excel without using an add on.

Comment: I did figure it out, thanks. I have to place the “onkey” command under ThisWorkbook for when it opens. So I would put it in “Private Sub Workbook_Open()”. Then I need to create a subroutine under ThisWorkbook and refer it to this routine. For the onkey routine to be ran make sure to specify “ThisWorkbook.Routine”, where “Routine” is the name of the new sub category. Otherwise you can create a module and whatever you called the Sub then you wouldn’t specify “ThisWorkbook.Routine” just specify “Routine”. I didn’t want to use a module though. Thanks for letting me know about the onkey!

Comment: This almost works like how I want it to. I opened another workbook to test, it carries over to other open workbook. I only want it to work for a specific workbook and not all open workbooks. Then if I close the workbook out that has the code and press those keys on a different workbook, it will reopen the workbook up with the code in it. In order to get the keys to stop working I have to close out of all sessions of Excel. Is there a way to make this code refer to this workbook strictly and not all workbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doug,

Thanks for your suggestion, I figured everything out due to that. Here it is, in case someone else finds this useful:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

    'When the workbook is active this will run the script in the place of the standard Ctrl + C.
    Application.onkey "^{c}", "ThisWorkbook.cCopy"

    End Sub


    Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    'When another workbook is active this will disable this script so the standard Ctrl + C will work again.
    Application.onkey "^{c}"

    End Sub


    Sub cCopy()

    'This is the script to run when active. This was used for testing purposes only.   
    Worksheets("Sites").Range("I1").Value2 = "Yes"

    End Sub
```